# Angular 7 calling Azure Indexer service

Tags: angular, azure, cors

I am trying to run an indexer that I have in Azure from a web app created in Angular. I found the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/run-indexer). However, this whenever I try to run the indexer according to this documentation I get blocked by CORS. Here is the code that calls the indexer in my service.ts

```
public async runIndex(){
        const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
            'api-key': "api-key's value here",
            'Accept': 'application/json'
            'content-type': 'application/json'});

        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('api-version', this.apiVersion);

        await this.speechHttp.post(this.indexUrl, params, {headers: httpHeaders}).subscribe(
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
```

This didn't work so I did more digging and among the articles I read, I found [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/index) that stated that API calls needed to be made from port 443. So I changed from Angular's default port 4200 to port 443 but that still does not work. I've tried creating a proxy file and then running `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`but that didn't work either. Is there any way to solve this issue in Angular? Last time I had a CORS issue with an API I created, I had to fix the problem on the server/API end of things, but I don't have access to the Azure Indexer's API.

Here is the CORS error message.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-indexer.search.windows.net/indexers/my-indexer/run?api-version=2019-05-06' from origin 'http://localhost:443' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It looks like the API is blocking the request even though the origin of the request is the suggested port 443.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [cannot access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Create-Index) the management APIs from a browser. This is to protect the admin keys as embedding them in a front end app is a security risk. You can set custom CORS definitions for the indexes themselve to allow them to be accessed via a browser, but this option is not available for indexers.

If you want to enable running an indexer from a web client, such as an admin area, you'll need to have your Angular app call your backend API and the API can make the call to Azure Search.

Comment: thanks that's what we ended up figuring that out and it works now